# Why I can't use ES6 function syntax as constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following code doesn't work:

```
let myClass = ()=>{
    this.value = 2
    return this
}

myClass.prototype.print = ()=>{
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

While this works

```
let myClass = function(){
    this.value = 2
    return this
}

myClass.prototype.print = function(){
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

What was the difference between ES6 function and regular function?

Comment: Because arrow function is not purposed to be used as a constructor, neither it is purposed to be used as a method. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is always useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions does not deal with `this` keyword the way it does with normal functions.

Inside arrow functions the value of `this` is same as what it is outside the function

Answer (score 2):

Because [arrow functions do not have a `prototype` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_prototype_property).

Comment: That's rather a consequence of them not being constructable, not the reason.